# JAVA Automatic Frame creator

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a spam of frames and i want to stop it when i press HOME key ,but it doesn't focus on the first frame(  which i can use the keylistener on ).  I tried without the first frame , just the ones in the loop with focus set on true but still doesn't work.

```
public class Script extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static boolean isTrue = true;

public Script(){
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_HOME)
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {


    JFrame frames = new Script();
    frames.setSize(300, 300);
    frames.setVisible(true);
    frames.setFocusable(true);
    frames.setLocation(800, 1000);
    frames.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    while(isTrue == true){

        int x = (int)(1+Math.random() * (1500-1));
        int y = (int)(1+Math.random() * (900-1));
        JFrame frame = new Script();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setFocusable(false);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocation(x, y);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}


}
```

}

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark my solution as answer if you could below.

Answer (score -1):

Never use an infinite while loop like that without `Thread.sleep`

Comment: My mistake I meant `Thread` instead of `Time`. I'm a Python programmer.